# How to install WSL2 without distro?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

In a fresh Windows 11, WSL2 can be installed via command running with privilege mode:

```
c:\> wsl --install
Installing: Virtual Machine Platform
Virtual Machine Platform has been installed.
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
Windows Subsystem for Linux has been installed.
Downloading: WSL Kernel
Installing: WSL Kernel
WSL Kernel has been installed.
Downloading: GUI App Support
[========================  41.8%                           ]
```

The command will install a default distro (e.g.: ubuntu) too.

Is there a way to install a WSL2 runtime and environment without any distro?

Comment: No; WSL2 requires a compatible Linux distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

<sub>*Windows 11 22H2 (and later) users, please see my [newer answer](https://superuser.com/a/1771795/1210833) for an easier method.  This may work on Windows 10 22H2 as well.*</sub>

---

Yes, if you'd like to defer installation of the distribution until later (likely to create a custom distribution), you can install the actual WSL2 "runtime and environment" without a distribution.

Just follow the first five steps of [Manual installation steps for older versions of WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual).  Those steps still work just fine on the current version.  A summary of those steps:

1. Enable WSL:  After this step, you will have WSL1 installed.  You could, at this point, `wsl --import` a rootfs tarball and have a working WSL1 environment.
2. Check requirements for running WSL 2
3. Enable the Virtual Machine feature. Reboot.
4. Install the WSL2 Linux kernel package
5. (Optional) Set WSL 2 as your default version using `wsl --set-default-version 2`.

At that point, you have full access to many of the `wsl` options, but you will be unable to actually start a distribution until you either:

- `wsl --import` a rootfs tarball/distribution
- Install a distribution from the Store
- `wsl install -d <distro>`

Comment: "there's not much you can do with WSL without an actual distribution installed" -- you can install a distribution that is not in the Windows Store.

Comment: @RobFisher Completely fair point -- I covered that at the end, but started out with an "unnecessarily  negative" outlook.  Finally got around to editing to fix that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Under Windows 11 22H2, you can now perform the initial installation of WSL without a distribution via:

```
wsl --install --no-distribution
```

As mentioned by @RobFisher in a comment to my earlier answer, this is useful if you want to install a custom distribution that isn't available in the Store, via `wsl --import`.  As mentioned in [@StevenWang's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1735911/1210833), it can also save upwards of 1GB of disk space if you intend to use Docker Desktop with PowerShell or CMD, but have no intention of using WSL itself directly.

I *believe* (but have not confirmed) that this will also work on the latest Windows 10 22H2 (and later) release, as long as you are up-to-date with the latest monthly service release.  If you haven't yet installed WSL, you can confirm whether (or not) the `--no-distribution` option shows in `wsl --help`.

Comment: This is the right approach for restoring a WSL2 instance to a new Windows installation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To install WSL without any distro, please DOT NOT use 'wsl -install' command via  the command line tools, just follow these steps.

1. Enable WSL features from 'Turn Windows features on or off'.
2. Update WSL kernel (not Linux distro kernel).

   ```
   wsl --update
   ```

OK, you can verify whether WSL works by `wls --status', you might get the following screen text.

```
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 2022-08-08
WSL automatic updates are on.

Kernel version: 5.10.102.1
```

Any you can try 'wsl --list' to check the installed Linux distros.

```
wsl --list

Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

See, there was no any Linux distros installed, and you can try Docker Desktop with WSL backend, when you install Docker Desktop, it would be your default distro.

Comment: WHY should we not use wsl -install? Considering the other answer has been accepted, meaning it worked, you're making a strong statement and you need to explain yourself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @music2myear wsl -install would install default Linux distro, but Chau Chee Yang want to know the way to install WSL without distro.